# Change default nginx location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am stuck in a scenario. I had nginx already installed on my linux server at /etc/nginx/ but it did not has passenger mod enabled. So i run

passenger-install-nginx-module

to but then in the wizard i chosen the option 1 to download and configure fresh nginx because i did not know the "source" location of previously installed nginx. So it downloaded and configure the nginx but at different location: **/opt/nginx/**

Now the problem is server is getting only previously installed at **/etc/nignx/**.

Do i have to change the default location somewhere? IF yes, then how? i couldnt find it anywhere on google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stop the nginx process running at /etc/nginx and then start the server from /opt/nginx.

```
 sudo /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx
```

will start nginx. You should have the root path set properly in the nginx conf.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried your solution but when i run server from /opt/nginx it says: Address already in use. Though i have stopped the prev server. Also, when i do "/etc/init.d/nginx restart" after change in any config.. it again tries to go /etc/nginx location.

Comment: Can you try ps ax | grep nginx. Then kill the process. Then start nginx using  sudo /opt/nginx/sbin/nginx. Dont do /etc/init.d/nginx restart.

Comment: Yes i am doing same right now and its working!. i wonder if  /etc/init.d/nginx restart could also work. As my deployment script runs this command after each deployment.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply backup your **/etc/nginx** somewhere, remove it and then make symbolic link with `ln /opt/nginx /etc -s` to point both places to the same location.